Unable to locate an element through selenium
I am trying to locate Vaccination date element using Selenium so that I can pass input as per my requirement but unable to do so using By.ID or By.XPATH.
id = 'mat-input-2'
XPATH = '//\*\[@id="mat-input-2"\]'

Code:
vaccination_date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-input-2"]').click()

HTML:
<div _ngcontent-lhj-c245="" class="col-md-4">
    <label _ngcontent-lhj-c245="" for="vaccinationDate" class="form-label">Vaccination Date<span _ngcontent-lhj-c245="" class="mandatory-field">*</span></label>
    <input _ngcontent-lhj-c245="" matinput="" formcontrolname="vaccinationDate" placeholder="  DD/MM/YYYY" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control mat-datepicker-input form-control vaccDate ng-pristine cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-valid ng-touched" id="mat-input-2" data-placeholder="  DD/MM/YYYY" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" aria-haspopup="dialog" max="2024-04-21T00:00:00+05:30" data-mat-calendar="mat-datepicker-2" min="2024-02-17T05:30:00+05:30">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle _ngcontent-lhj-c245="" matsuffix="" class="mat-datepicker-toggle picker" data-mat-calendar="mat-datepicker-2">
        <button mat-icon-button="" type="button" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-icon-button mat-button-base" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-label="Open calendar" tabindex="0">
            <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" fill="currentColor" focusable="false" class="mat-datepicker-toggle-default-icon ng-star-inserted">
                    <path d="M19 3h-1V1h-2v2H8V1H6v2H5c-1.11 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L3 19c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 16H5V8h14v11zM7 10h5v5H7z"></path>
                </svg>
                <!---->
            </span>
            <span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple mat-button-ripple-round"></span>
            <span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span>
        </button>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker _ngcontent-lhj-c245=""></mat-datepicker>
    <!---->
    <span _ngcontent-lhj-c245="" class="alert-message ng-star-inserted">       <!----><!----><!----><!---->    </span>
    <!---->
</div>

I have tried this:
vaccination_date = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'mat-input-2').click()
vaccination_date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-input-2"]').click()

